# What does Microsoft Forms Error 800a01a8 mean?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

[Picture of Office Applications Sync Turned Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx0dZ.png) [Picture of Error Received at Workbook Close and Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjtbZ.png) I have a workbook that is an "Import Sheet" for our users to enter information either via manual entry, data validation drop downs, or userform. Everything works great until I close the workbook and tell it to save. I receive this error:

"Microsoft Forms (<- Title) Could not complete the operation due to error 800a01a8."

I thought originally it might have something to do with interrupting the OneDrive/Sharepoint sync but based on my internet sleuthing I've discovered that you can prevent the sync from happening by going into the OneDrive settings and unchecking the "Use Office applications to sync Office files" option and it doesn't seem to be syncing upon close anymore, however my problem persists. I am unable to find much on this specific error, if anyone has any ideas please let me know. I would be willing to provide code if someone could point me in the right direction of which code could be the problem (i.e. - BeforeClose sub, BeforeSave sub, etc.) If someone is so inclined to dig deep enough I'd provide the whole workbook purely in the interest of resolving this issue.